# Why is the Alphabet shorter at Christmas time?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Why is the Alphabet shorter at Christmas time?

Hint: look at the word "Christmas"

Comment: I'm sure I got this in a cracker once...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think this is the answer, but I'm not entirely sure...

> The word "Christmas" has no "L" --> "Noel"

but I lowkey don't think it's right...

Comment: My response would have been "Because there is no L"  (Noel).

Answer (score 12):

Took a shot at it..

> Someone yells "Christ, Ma (my) 'S'!" like when you drop your S on the floor, so obviously the S is missing.

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a legit answer for wordplay.

Comment: This makes exactly as much sense as the correct answer.

Comment: @AJFaraday No, It's better than the correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

The answer to this question goes back to the song, *Christmas Alphabet* by *Dickie Valentine*. Why, you ask?

```
C is for the candy trimmed around the christmas tree,
H is for the happiness with all the family,
R is for the reindeer prancing by the window pane,
I is for the icing on the cake as sweet as sugar cane,
S is for the stocking hanging on the chimney wall,
T is for the toys beneath the tree so tall,
M is for the misletoe where everyone is kissed,
A is for the angels who make up the christmas list,
S is for the santa who makes every kid his pet
```

That's right, according to dear Uncle Dickie. The Alphabet has only got 9 letters, and only 8 of those are unique letters (note the two instances of S).

How'd I do? ;)

Answer (score 4):

I think this could be an alternative answer to what is already provided:

> Christmas is sometimes known by its abbreviation Xmas. Alphabetically, we are taking the Christ out of the Christmas. Interesting fact: There's a common myth that Xmas is a modern term for "taking the Christ out of Christmas" -- for being disrespectful to those of Christian faith. But Xmas is a legitimate term that is as old as Christianity itself and does not have a demeaning purpose.

Comment: It's a slightly more complex debate than that, because it definitely is used to hide the "Christ" part, particularly in commercial contexts. You're probably thinking of the Greek equivalent of X being the first character of Christ in Greek, the language of the new testament. However, the word Christmas, and indeed the word Christian, is somewhat newer than the Christian faith ;)

Comment: I thought that the term (in modern times) was mainly intended to save space and costs on advertisements -- a 5 letter savings. But I guess that turned into the moral panic that it is today.

Answer (score 4):

I know an answer has been selected but I thought of a little silly answer similar to kedarguru

> Christmas can be abbreviated Xmas. "Xmas" kind of sounds like "X miss". So we miss X during Christmas time i.e. "X miss time".